# I'm having a problem rendering in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekIsI.png)0

I am a newbie Blender user. I made my project yesterday and tried to render it in Google Colab. I ran a code which worked for a Youtuber who is running Blender2.93, but the same code showed error when I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

try to render it in blender itself rather than in colab.
increase core count to max in cpu settings
if gpu available try to render with it and run it evee